# HTML editor for Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Please review this simple code. When I review it I decide to rewrite so that it doesn't write to a template, but instead directly to output since the whole HTML is fetched from the data layer. I used the tool `appengine_admin` to get editable HTML for simple html capabilities to an appspot project:

```
    class Page(db.Model):
      html = db.TextProperty(required=True)

    class AdminPage(appengine_admin.ModelAdmin):

        model = Page
        listFields = (
            'html',
            )
        editFields = (
            'html',
            )



  application = webapp.WSGIApplication([  ('/page/([0-9]+)', PageHandler), ])

  class PageHandler(BaseHandler):
      def get(self, file_id):
        page = Page.get_by_id(long(file_id))
        if not page:
          self.error(404)
          return
        self.render_template(file_id+'.html', {
            'body': page.body,
        })
```

My 2 to-dos:

1. change variable `file_id` to `page_id`
2. change writing to direct output instead of template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication([  ('/page/([0-9]+)', PageHandler), ])
```

I'd put the list of urls as a global constant, I think that would make it easier to read.

```
  class PageHandler(BaseHandler):
      def get(self, file_id):
        page = Page.get_by_id(long(file_id))
        if not page:
```

If you are checking against None here, I'd  use `if page is None:`

```
  self.error(404)
  return
```

I'd use else instead of returning here

```
self.render_template(file_id+'.html', {
    'body': page.body,
})
```